# Individual connection of people via ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-tunneling, ssh-agent

I have different users on the server and each of them has a username and password

I want each user with his own username to be able to connect to the server with only one device at a time and not to be able to connect to the same username with multiple devices at any time.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: one question would be "why?", esp. since if they have shell access, they can run commands in the background, and if you have a general-purpose system with something like `screen` or `tmux` installed, they'd allow multiple emulated terminals. What is it that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: What should happen if a user is accidentally disconnected and they try to log in again?

Comment: If you want something like that on a user-based level, you'd likely need to create an authentication module (e.g. PAM) to do that. Or have the users' shell do some check when starting, if it's one that can do that without the user having an option of bypassing it

Comment: `pam_exec` maybe. But think through the implications of permitting only a single concurrent login very carefully

Comment: in concrete: a possible problem here would be the connection dropping on the client side, but the SSH server process staying alive on the server for some while before noticing the connection was gone. If that'd happen, the user couldn't start a new session since they'd show up as already logged in, but also couldn't use the old session.